# Open Office Calc truncates my data on paste, how do I fix this?

Tags: openoffice, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

Just as the title says, I am using Open Office Calc as a flat file to upload data. One column is my description and therefore can be a bit lengthy. Unfortunately it truncates this text. Anyway to extend the limit?

Comment: Anyone? Just got the tumbleweed badge for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to duplicate this problem and here's what I found using a string of text approximately 150 characters long.  This may or may not be considered lengthy by you since you didn't specify how lengthy lengthy was.  I put my string of text into a text file.

First I imported the text file into a spreadsheet as a CSV file type.  It put each word into a seperate cell.  I'm sure that wouldn't be acceptable to you.

I then placed the text in between double quotes and again imported it into a spreadsheet as a CSV file type.  It put the whole string into one cell, however, several characters were shown in the cell to the right.  By clicking on the cell where the text string starts, the whole text string shows up in the text editing area.  If there is data in the string to the right, then the characters extending into that cell from the cell the text was inserted into disappear, but, again, clicking on the text string cell the whole string shows up in the editing window.

I then started a new spreadsheet and in a window used "cat" to display the contents of the text string file.  I then high-lighted the text string to cut and paste it into the spreadsheet.  It all came into the spreadsheet, but if there was data in the cell to the right it appeared to be truncated, but was actually all there.

Sorry, I was not able to duplicate your problem.  I hope that my testing help by giving you some ideas to try.

Regards,

Rich